# Python dictionary to loop csv headers for plotting

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Python newbie here, my goal is to load a csv into a dataframe so I can loop through each header to plot individual distributions.

I want to use a dictionary to store the headers as keys and data as a list of values like this:

```
header1: [1,2,3,4,5]
header2: [6,7,8,9,10]
```

I then want to iterate through all headers in my header_list (Not sure if this is the best approach) to plot.

```
PATH="/Users/Myname/Desktop/PFA/"
df=pd.read_csv(PATH + 'my_input.csv', sep=',',header=None)

#2nd row in csv is headers
header=df.iloc[[1]]

fom = dict()

for i in header_list:
     for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
         plt.plot(fom[key])
         plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated. You can probably tell I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Is your code working? If yes, where is the question? If no, what does it do and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Also add the an example csv file so that we can get the context

Answer (score 0):

You can better loop over df.columns

```
df = pd.read_csv(PATH + 'my_input.csv', sep=',', header=True)

# df.columns has the header
for column in df.columns:
    plt.plot(df[column], label=column)
plt.show()
```